# Difference between predicate-argument structure (spo) and RDF triple

Tags: nlp, rdf

I am learning about extracting information from sentences and ask to extract the spo structure and RDF triple of the following sentences:

- Steel is an alloy.
- Steel contains carbon.
- Steel contains iron.

But I think both RDF triple and spo structure of the sentences are:

- (Steel, is, an alloy)
- (Steel, contains, carbon)
- (Steel, contains, iron)

May I know if I am doing it correctly and what are the differences between the two?

Comment: What do you mean by "both answers are the same"? And are you mapping to any ontology, e.g. is the string "is" mapped to `rdf:type` for example?

Comment: By the way, you may try [this](https://permid.org/onecalaisViewer) with a news article, and then compare relations with the corresponding part in the text and in the generated RDF. It may give you some insights.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov Thanks for the link, I will have a look later, I have update the question to make it more clear.